# Issue with xticklabels when saving a figure with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a wonderful figure which appears excellent when working in a jupyter notebook but will not save as it appears in the notebook - the primary issue is the last xticklabel is always missing! I have tried numerous things including using `tight_layout`, saving with `bbox_inches='tight'`, and adjusting the spacing with `subplot_adjust` - nothing seems to work!

#### This is how it appears in juypyter lab:

[image]

#### This is how the figure saves:

[image]

#### Here is a snippet that re-creates the issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter
from datetime import timedelta

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=24*60, freq='min'), name='value')

df = pd.DataFrame(ts, columns=['value'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 4))
ax.plot(df.value)


ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(date2num(df.index[0]), date2num(df.index[0] + timedelta(hours=24)), 5))
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(date2num(df.index[0]), date2num(df.index[0] + timedelta(hours=24)), 25), minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%I %p"))

ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])

fig.savefig("tmp.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

How can I reliably save figures with matplotlib...?

I am using matplotlib v2.2.2 with the MacOSX backend.

Comment: What version of matplotlib and which backend are you using? (i.e. the value of `plt.matplotlib.__version__` and `plt.matplotlib.get_backend()`). I was not able to reproduce the issue using matplotlib 2.2.0 / GTK3Cairo, and with `rng = range(1440)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @unutbu - added those as edits.

Comment: Same here. Can't reproduce this error with 2.2.2 and TkAgg, though it is on Ubuntu.

Comment: Interesting - so if I use Qt5 or TkAgg and save via the GUI, it works great; however, the savefig method still screws it up. Not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Do you both see the correct output upon saving? Or just in the GUI/notebook?

Comment: I ran the code from the command line, and `tmp.png` includes the right ticklabel at 12AM.

Comment: What happens if you use `plt.switch_backend(backend) ` to set a different backend? (Check `plt.matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends` for possible choices).

Comment: Just tried with Qt5 and TkAgg, both of which both exhibit the same issue. This is weird. I'll try on a PC and ubuntu later; maybe it is OS dependant?

Comment: Since Mr. T didn't reproduce the problem on 2.2.2/TkAgg/Ubuntu, but you see the problem on 2.2.2/TkAgg/OSX, perhaps it is OS dependent (or Python/NumPy version dependent?). Ironically, since `df.index[-1]` equals `Timestamp('2011-01-01 23:59:00', freq='T')` which is *before* 12AM, it could be argued that you are getting the correct behavior and Mr. T and I are experiencing a bug.

Comment: What happens if you change `ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])` to `ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('1/1/2011'), pd.Timestamp('1/2/2011'))`?

Comment: To add information: Yes, the saved file contained the right label. Python 3.5.2, Numpy 1.14.2, Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: @unutbu I changed `ax.set_xlim()` as suggested and that seems to do the trick! I wonder why a) it's different on different platforms and b) why it renders fine in jupyter but doesn't save correctly? I also think your comment on whether I or you are seeing the "bug" is an interesting one..

Comment: You might be able to get an answer by [posting an issue here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).